# Clear Angularjs state.go parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on angularjs app. Its like CRUD app. Below is the app structure

```
Home (List)        => "/#!/"
--- Details page   => "/#!/home/details/-KcXruMX3ia6rokeZjCJ"
----- Edit page    => "#!/home/edit/-KcXruMX3ia6rokeZjCJ"
```

After edit page I redirect user to details page with success message as below.

```
$scope.msg = {type : "success","msg" : "User Updated"};
$state.go('home.details', { id : $scope.id, msg : $scope.msg });
```

Till this step it works fine, Problem is when I click on other user/item  and come to details page I still see that message.

Below is my details controller

```
myApp.controller("detailsCtrl",[
        "$scope",
        "$stateParams",
    function(
        $scope, 
        $stateParams, 
    ){
    // msg variables receives its values from previous actions 
    $scope.msg = $stateParams.msg;

}]);
```

How can I clear that message by using it once ?

Comment: when the detail page loading can you make `$scope.msg = {}`

Comment: Then it will not show success message.

Comment: How do you go to the details page? If you are using `ui-sref` then threre you can also provide the state params like `ui-sref="details({msg: ''})"` or if you want to clear the state params, when you are transitioning into current state you can mention `$state.go('.', {msg: undefined} );`

Comment: @Gaurav : Ahha thats it, thats what i wanted. ui-sref="details({msg: ''})". Can you please post it as answer so i can mark it as solved.

Comment: I've added that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `ui-sref` then threre you can also provide the state params like `ui-sref="details({msg: ''})"` or if you want to clear the state params, when you are transitioning into current state you can mention `$state.go('.', {msg: undefined} );`