# angular ui-router params not clear

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state:

```
.state({
        name: "some_url",
        url: "/some",
        templateUrl: "views/some.html",
        controller: 'someCtrl',
        params: {
            someData: {
                'mout': null,
            }
        }
    })
```

Then in controller i change it:

```
$scope.someData = $stateParams.someData;
$scope.someData['mykey'] = 2;
```

and go to next url:

```
$state.go("next_url");
```

And in next url if i do:

`console.log($stateParams.someData)` i get undefined which is ok.

But if after this i will go back to `$state.go("some_url");` then:

```
console.log($stateParams.someData)
```

Shows me:

```
{'mykey': 2}
```

How to clear `stateParams` ?

Comment: Are you going back with the browser back button or via `state.go` ?

Comment: It goes inside controller again and reassigns your `$stateParams`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular creates a singleton object, so you have to clear before execute the state

try to use

//    $state.go(state, params, options);

```
$state.go("some_url", null, {reload:true});
```

Comment: how do i do this in html: ```<md-button ui-sref="some_url">BACK</md-button>``` ?

Comment: please check 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42445910/clear-angularjs-state-go-parameters/42447456#42447456

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$state.go("some_url", null, {reload:true});
```

in HTML you can do it with *ui-sref-opts* parameter

```
<md-button ui-sref="some_url" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}" >BACK</md-button>
```

[Reference](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref)