# Reset all $stateParams to their default

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How do I reset all $stateParams to their defined default? Of course, I could reset them by hand like:

```
$state.go(".", {
  param1: "",
  param2: 0,
  param3: false
});
```

But it would be nice to auto reset to their defined default.

```
$stateProvider
  .state("myState", {
    url: "?param1&param2&param3",
    params: {
      param1: {
        value: "",
        type: "string",
        squash: true
      }, 
      param2: {
        value: 0,
        type: "int",
        squash: true
      }, 
      param3: {
        value: false,
        type: "bool",
        squash: true
      }
    }
  });
```

Doing it manually forces me to look up every parameters value, before setting a value.

And I totally do NOT want to set everything to undefined, as this may break some logics.

**EDIT**

Adding version info:

- AngularJS 1.6.3
- UI-Router: 1.0.0-beta.3

Comment: please check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42445910/clear-angularjs-state-go-parameters/42447456#42447456](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42445910/clear-angularjs-state-go-parameters/42447456#42447456)

Comment: The method described there is exactly what I do NOT want to do, passing every parameter with `undefined`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late but if someone as the same problem:

You can set the **inherit** TransitionOptions to false to force the default value of params.

```
$state.go(".", {param1: ""}, {inherit: false});
```

See doc here:
https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/transition.transitionoptions.html#inherit

Comment: Nice! I never recognised this option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ui-sref then threre you can also provide the state params like `ui-sref="details({msg: ''})` or if you want to clear the state params, when you are transitioning into current state you can mention `$state.go('.', {msg: undefined} );`